# Testing for insulation for asbestos?

Tags: insulation, asbestos

Should we be worried about asbestos with this loose-fill insulation? New England house from the 1860s. No idea when the insulation was added but the attic space is extremely difficult to access.

[image]
[image]

Comment: what exactly are you trying to ask?

Comment: The question is in the first sentence of the post. But you are right! It is not a good question. I did some research and pretty much arrived as @jwh20 answer. So why ask? It's going to take 2+ weeks to test and I was freaking out because we had an electrician pulling wires all over the place with plenty of that stuff coming from the ceiling. So I guess I had some shimmer of hope that someone is going to tell me testing is unnecessary.

Comment: wow .... the electrician should not have disturbed that insulation .... that shows a "don't care" attitude ... you better check the electrician's work closely .... no telling what else the electrician does not care about

Comment: maybe, I've seen plenty of electricians that are ok at electrician-ing (I just made that word up I think) but absolutely HORRIBLE at messing up the structure, badly patched walls, messing with insulation like above or not replacing it leaving voids, drilling holes through vital areas of structural members, etc. I agree it's a red flag and should be looked into, though I want note that one doesn't necessarily mean the other and so not to unnecessarily frighten anyone reading this

Comment: "all over the place" is exaggerated but it did fall from the ceiling, which is impossible to avoid when you cut or drill any hole, change an electrical box etc. Still never mentioned anything or show any concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should get it tested.

There is absolutely no way of knowing by looking at it and this home is old enough to have used building products from before the dangers of asbestos were known.

Comment: If you shop around and maybe take in your test to a local lab, both should keep the price down and within reason. I had my water tested for lead for $25 including a lab report. The lab I used do it not for profit but as a community service, they usually do much larger projects.